# How do I plan/manage a large project?

Tags: c++11, project-management, project-planning

In my Object Oriented design class, we have a final project to construct a Casino with Blackjack, Craps, Texas Hold'em and Slots. We are also able to have 2 - 3 people per project.

This is the largest project I've ever done thus far, and I'm looking for (general) guidance on how to properly plan a project out before coding begins, so that I don't end up chasing my tail.

Also, I'm interested in how to effectively divide the workload between people. (For example: Is it better to just have one person work on one class?)

Additionally, I'm interested in any suggestions regarding repositories (GIT, etc.) and if they would make sense in this case or not.

I'm looking for general guidance steps to follow, but not specific to my project. I'd like to learn a solid, tried and true method so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Y'know this question probably violates some rule but I think it's got merit.

Comment: For reference, we'll need your ideas, what you've tried to achieve (or what you think you'll try) etc. What's your desired result (time wise, product design etc). Kinda a broad question but I stand by that I think it's got merit

Comment: @edplunkett you were a student once.

Comment: The question has merit, but whether it's on-topic for SO is another matter.

Comment: Divide and conquer. Break down you bigger tasks into smaller tasks until they are the right size to assign to people. Let people be responsible for features, and they will determine what code should be written from there. Set goals, work in sprints, review your progress and re-asses your goals.

Comment: Can we move this to a more relevant site instead of closing?

Comment: @edplunkett then you should know better than to judge them all by a bad bunch. SO is all about helping one another out. I get you might have been humorous in your reply but still, this dude is here asking the best ways to go about stuff that he'll later use (hopefully) in a relevant role rather than drinking/smoking his life away.

Comment: @edplunkett "thick head young clown" now was that appropriate?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about project management, which, per the [project-management] tag, is now off-topic.  See http://pm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: When assigning tasks, my advice is to let people work on things they want to work on, even if you think it will be challenging for them.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methodologies to manage a project (waterfall, agile etc). But you can start with following simple steps for managing your first project.

1. As a team come up with all the tasks needed to complete the project. (e-g, capturing requirements, design, and subtasks for implementations, testing, deployment etc), independent of who is going to work on the tasks. (You can use any spread sheet to do this exercise) (This is called Work break down structure). Break down the tasks at very logical level which independently can be done by one person.
2. Then conduct planning exercise again with the team and assign right resource (person) to do the job and get the number of days/weeks he/she will take to complete the job. The last task in your planning excel sheet is your project completion date.
3. Track the progress of each tasks you captured in the excel by conducting status update meetings. (There may be lot of unknown surprises which may derail your original plan (risks) during the course of the project, best way to handle them is predict them as much as possible have a plan B for each one of them (mitigation)).

Have source repositories helps to have multiple people working on same code base and also a great back up mechanism for source control. Github is good one.

Key here is, capturing all the required tasks upfront and having people to do it. Second most important task is how you can come up with a design which is modular and work together when integrated, this helps to distribute the work with multiple people. Third how much you can predict unknowns which you can have upfront plan for it.

Most importantly, project management is not science, and it is more of an art which you learn by doing it many different projects and different people.